# Regex which contains 12 digits numbers or symbol including special characters

Tags: regex, forms, validation, regex-negation

If have this regex

```
^\d(?:[-\s]?\d){6,11}$
```

but it doesn't fit all the conditions given below.

1. Allowed amount of digits: 12 (including dash/hyphen).
2. The field should allow: Numbers and Symbols only (no letters)

Example of a business registration number: `18129561-000`

Comment: So, do you mean 12 is the length limit for the whole string? What are valid and what are invalid strings?

Comment: yes 12 is the length but contains only numbers and symbols(no letters). Also  has special characters(-,/,@.#,$)

Comment: How many numbers and how many special characters should there be?

Comment: `/^[0-9-]{6,12}$` would mean: allow between 6 and 12 characters in the set numbers and hyphens.

Comment: ^[\d-]{12}$ this is working but i want special characters also like _@#

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this one:

```
\b[\d\-\/@#$]{12}\b
```

Explanation and test [here](https://regex101.com/r/vi7hi1/4)

Comment: ^[\d\-\/@#$_]{12}$  Thank you so much ...This is the one which i actually want